# node.js listen to process error event

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a way somehow to listen to event for node process
like **process.stderr**, I want event that when this line is invoked to do some logic inside, any idea if it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to listen to the child process spawned from your nodejs server, its simple, i have given the example below.

Note: its very unclear to guess what you mean

```
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

        var child = spawn('myshell.sh', []);

        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('stdout- ' + data);
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('stderr- ' + data);
        });     
        child.on('exit', function (code) {
            console.log('exit - ' + code);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks I already do that but it seems that noon of the event you provide (and also 'error' ) is not invoked in case of error the only thing which bring the error is the child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr); and I need somethow to use it in event,any idea?